# mpdf set font arial not working

Tags: mpdf

I am using mpdf 6.0 to create PDF from a html form.
I want to use Arial font. In my css file there is:
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

in Mpdf in the "config_fonts.php" file I have activated the font directory:

```
define("_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", 'C:/Windows/Fonts/');
```

then;

```
$this->backupSubsFont = array('arial','dejavusanscondensed','freeserif');
```

and;

```
$this->fonttrans = array(
'arial' => 'arial',
'times' => 'timesnewroman',
'courier' => 'couriernew',
'trebuchet' => 'trebuchetms',
'comic' => 'comicsansms',
'franklin' => 'franklingothicbook',
'ocr-b' => 'ocrb',
'ocr-b10bt' => 'ocrb',
'damase' => 'mph2bdamase');
```

But anyway the PDF file which is produced contains always the font 
dejavu sans condensed and not arial.

any ideas?
thanks a lot.

regards
hawk

Comment: Has nobody an idea how to include font Arial into mPDF?

Answer (score 1):

Download and move the Arial font TTF into the `ttfonts` folder and declare it manually in **config_fonts.php**.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['default_font' => 'arial']);
```

You can read more in the documentation:
https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/default-font.html